# How do I edit the default 'Sign In' and 'Create Account' pages that are implemented by AWS Amplify's authentication service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, frontend, aws-amplify

I've created an Amplify-React app and implemented AWS Amplify's own authentication service. This creates default 'Sign In' and 'Create Account' pages. I'd like to edit the look of those pages by perhaps changing the text font or the colour of buttons etc. Does anyone know how I'd do this?

I haven't tried anything yet as I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Amplify allows you to customize it easily.
Follow the documentation here: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/customization

Comment: Don't know how I missed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/) and build your own front-end solution.

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signIn() {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing in', error);
    }
}
```

Use react to control state, and pass in the values.

Here is a [tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/react/#option-2-follow-the-instructions) you can follow.